# Where is the XPM preview webservice called from?

Tags: experience-manager

When implementing and using Experience manager, can anyone shed any information as to where calls to the preview web service originate from?

The editor is obviously part of the content management server, and is exposed within the CM Explorer. But do the calls to the preview webservice originate from the client's machine or from the content manager server when a component is changed?

This has security/firewall implications for us as our CM servers are on a different domain from the client machines.

Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The calls originate from the Content Manager server(s), not from the client(s).

More details of the actual flow of actions on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10802033/866454).

Comment: In addition to the steps outlined in Nuno's (linked) answer, you may find Julian's Whiteboarding Experience Manager video useful: http://www.julianwraith.com/2013/11/sdl-tridion-whiteboarding-experience-manager/

Comment: Nuno, many thanks for providing that link... a clear explanation that will guide us well as we set up XPM.